# mysql date direct subtraction

Tags: mysql, date

I have a two date columns, `dateA` and `dateB`. If I subtract `dateA` from `dateB` (`dateB - dateA`), I get wrong results but not using `DATEDIFF(dateB,dateA)`function. I get wrong result from direct subtraction when used in a table with data but not with below query.

`SELECT DATE('2013-01-31') - DATE('2013-01-27')`

Why?

EDIT:

I found that in MySQL if the two dates are within a month then direct subtraction gives correct result but if the dates span month, year there might be a problem.

Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Are your column's defined as date, or as Varchars? Because Date as a String means nothing. When you do a `DATE('2013-01-31')`, it creates a date object and hence the subtraction works. So, if your column is defined as Varchar, do `DATE(dateB) - DATE(dateA)`.

Comment: It's confirmed that the two fields are Date fields.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you columns are not stored as dates, but as strings.  If they were stored as dates, then subtraction would work as expected.

When you subtract two strings, such as:

```
SELECT '2013-01-31' - '2013-01-27'
```

Then MySQL converts them to numbers, based on the leading digits.  In this case, both start with the numbers `2013`, so both are converted to `2013` (if there were no digits at the beginning then the value would be `0`).  These numbers are then subtracted.

Comment: It's confirmed that the two fields are Date fields

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT '2013-01-31' - '2012-12-27';
+-----------------------------+
| '2013-01-31' - '2012-12-27' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE('2013-01-31') - DATE('2012-12-27');
+-----------------------------------------+
| DATE('2013-01-31') - DATE('2012-12-27') |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                    8904 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-01-31', '2012-12-27');
+--------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF('2013-01-31', '2012-12-27') |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                   35 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE('2013-01-31'), DATE('2012-12-27'));
+--------------------------------------------------+
| DATEDIFF(DATE('2013-01-31'), DATE('2012-12-27')) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                               35 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```